# For frequency 365 i am getting straight line in forecasting while i think it should be a zig zag graph

Tags: r, graph, frequency, rjava

I want draw a zig zag graph with proper date format while it show date like 2001.00,2001.01 etc

```
#import forecast library

library('forecast');

#prepare rawdata object for froecating

rawdata <- read.csv('bigDataSet6.csv',sep=',' ,head=TRUE);

attach(rawdata);

#attach data object in r
head(rawdata);

rawdata$Date <- as.Date(rawdata$Date);

#Using build in ts object

sts = ts(rawdata$Sale, start=2001, frequency=365);

#set Forecasting model

model.ets = ets(sts, model='ANA');


fc.ets = forecast(model.ets,12);

# plot graph
plot(fc.ets)
```

Please suggest if something is wrong in my code

Comment: To start with there is a `)` missing right at the bottom of your code.

Comment: also perhaps you should give the output of a `dput(rawdata)` or at least part of `rawdata` as nobody but you has `bigDataSet6.csv` and therefore this is not [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) .

Comment: also you do not need the `""` around `forecast` in `library()` or any of the semicolons since you use new lines for each line of code